# Were to make calculations on data from react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on my first webapp and at the start I focused on the visual aspect of displaying data. One of my components is a grid-based horizontal list of dates. Now as you see I just grab from the .json starting date and ending date. Based on it I create an array of all days from a range to display in my component.

Now I want to make this component work with user input data for starting and ending date. If I will use redux to keep startDate and endDate in the global state where I should make those 'calculations' like creating an array of days between a range?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import GanttDayCell from 'components/atoms/GanttDayCell/GanttDayCell';
import SampleData from 'data/SampleData.json';
import moment from 'moment';

const startDate = moment(SampleData.dateRange.startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
const endDate = moment(SampleData.dateRange.endDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

const days = [];

let currentDay = startDate;

while (currentDay.format('X') <= endDate.format('X')) {
  days.push(currentDay.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
  currentDay = currentDay.add(1, 'd');
}

const numberOfDays = days.map(day => <GanttDayCell key={day} day={day} />);

const StyledDaysRow = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(26, 30, 35, 1) 0%, rgba(22, 25, 29, 1) 100%);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(${days.length}, 125px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #121418;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #121418;
    height: 8px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;

    border: 1px solid #121418;
    background-color: #0067ff;
  }
`;

const DaysRow = () => (

      <StyledDaysRow id="daysArea">
        {numberOfDays}
      </StyledDaysRow>
);

export default DaysRow;
```

Comment: calculations in render (derived) - it's to early for redux - learn react basics from some todo tutorial

Comment: can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: passing data as props, rendering view from props

Comment: Still not sure what you mean but I made startDate, endDate, and days array here just to test if my components will display data correctly and I don't want to keep it that way.

Comment: back with something normal or better [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

*If* you're using a state management library like Redux, I'd recommend putting *derived state* in *selectors*. You can use a library like [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) or simply create a function of `state`. For example:

```js
const getDataRange = state => {
  const dateRange = // Calculate date range here
  return dateRange;
}
```

And then, in your component, you can use the selector in `mapStateTopProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  dateRange: getDateRange(state)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add Redux you can have access of startDate and endDate in the DaysRow component. For example,you can do it in this way

```js
const numberOfDays = (startDate,endDate) => {
const days = [];

let currentDay = startDate;

while (currentDay.format('X') <= endDate.format('X')) {
  days.push(currentDay.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
  currentDay = currentDay.add(1, 'd');
}

 return days.map(day => <GanttDayCell key={day} day={day} />);
}
const DaysRow = ({startDate,endDate}) => (
    <StyledDaysRow id="daysArea">
        {numberOfDays(startDate,endDate)}
    </StyledDaysRow>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    startDate:state.startDate,
    endDate: state.endDate
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(DaysDate)
```

Comment: Thats a good solution too. Thanks for finding time to explain such basic things to a noob like me.